# Logging the bytes going to IIS

Tags: iis, logging

I have a web service running on IIS that is rejecting data being send from ATG. It fails before it gets to my web service code, and the error message is badly formed XML.

I want to get logging started on the IIS front end so I can see the body of the request before it dies in the SOAP marshaller, but I can't seem to find the way to do it. I followed along with the brutal log process, but the recommended log parser 2.2 just spews out lots of message boxes and no text output.

This seems pretty straightforward in IIS 7 but in IIS6 it seems impossibly difficult. Am I missing something? Is there a simple, easy to use tool to turn it on in IIS 6, and easily view the results? I need to see the actual body of the XML not just the headers, so the logging in the properties tab of IIS Manager doesn't produce enough information.

Thanks.

Comment: If this web service is .NET based, you may also use System.Net tracing to see the raw bytes (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947285)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One non-IIS way of doing this would be to install a packet capture program on the server, start a capture, wait until the problem occurs, stop the capture, and analyze the capture details. [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865) will let you easily drill into the capture based on process, conversation, etc.